# SVG animation acts funny in firefox

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

this is the code for the SVG animation.

[This is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26amopbw/)

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
#rotate {
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   transform-box: fill-box;
   animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
}
#rotate > rect {
    transform: translate(12px, 12px);
}
```

```html
<svg id="H1XgaUeE3lX" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 363 387">
<g id="rotate">
<rect x="50" width="100" height="20" y="50"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

the animation changes depending on which browser I open the code in. 
it works fine in chrome but doesn't work in Firefox.

the axis of rotation changes depending on which brouser it is opened in.

Comment: So since I am in a good mood, here is a real [MCVE](https://jsfiddle.net/26amopbw/). Feel free to include it in a code snippet as an [edit] to your question. (And to me, FF's behavior makes more sense).

Comment: thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I am not too used with this `transform-box: fill-box` and IIRC specs were not yet tied about it not so long ago. But for a quick fix, apply your transforms on the enclosed element since it seems that even in [your own code](https://jsfiddle.net/drwe6t05/6) there is only one element in every `<g>`.

Comment: And actually the discrepancy can already be seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4oqjypb/)  (FF sets the `<g>`'s BBox diregarding content"s inner-transform)

Comment: I reformated the code I posted [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drwe6t05/19/)